# Start Excel with command line and parameters

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

I want to create a Windows script to execute excel and open a file p and using the password

Example

```
Start excel c:\Documents\ExcelFile.xls
```

but also I want to add the password

```
Start excel c:\Documents\ExcelFile.xls Password
```

But when I try to do that is not recognized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `PowerShell` script to perform that using [Workbook Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open) function.

```
$path = "c:\temp\1.xls"
$password = "123"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path,$false,$false,5,$password)
$excel.Visible = $true
```

Save the script to a text file `OpenExcel.ps1`.

Usage:

```
powershell -file OpenExcel.ps1
```

Comment: Thank you im going to test :D

Answer (score 3):

Excel has no command line switch to submit a password.
See [Command-line switches for Microsoft Office products](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Excel)

But you can use a VBScript `StartExcel.vbs` instead of a batch file `StartExcel.bat` to do that:

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\Documents\ExcelFile.xls", 0, 0, 5, "<myPassword")
```

Comment: Thank you I'm going to test :D